# How to use python to do the web development (or how to set uo cgi)

Tags: python

As the title said, just wonderring how to use python or anyhow to include executable python script into HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using django to do this.

django official web:
https://www.djangoproject.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html) for learning about Python in the web.  But more specifically, there is documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#module-cgi) explaining Common Gateway Interface (CGI) and how to use it.  I recommend looking into this first because I am unsure what exactly you need help with, if it is simply wondering how it works, then these links will explain that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is very simple micro framework for writing web applications in python.

http://flask.pocoo.org